# Can people having worked in a company for several years be called "oldcomer"?

Tags: word-usage

> Many young employees have been hired by our company this year. Most of
>   them are students who graduated from university recently. So can they
>   be called "newcomers of our company"?  Can old employers who have
>   worked in our company for several years be called "oldcomers" ?

Comment: There is a [related discussion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/139487/whats-the-opposite-of-newcomer-is-veteran-ok). Better choices than "oldcomer" (which I've never heard) would be "veteran,"  "old-timer," or "old hand."

Comment: "Old-timer" is the idiomatic expression (in the US), but it can be interpreted as pejorative.

Comment: Didn't you already ask this 4 years ago https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/139487/whats-the-opposite-of-newcomer-is-veteran-ok

Answer (score 2):

The better description for mature people who have served time is **old hand**

> **Old Hand**
>   a person with a lot of experience in something.
>   [- Google Dictionary](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=old+hand&oq=old+hand&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1609j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

As commented, above, a number of other words have a pejorative flavour to them but 'old hand' is more a term of endearment and a recognition of experienced loyalty, rather than a comment on elderliness, as such.

[The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/an+old+hand)

> Note: You can describe someone as **an older hand** when you are comparing them with someone who is less experienced.

**Newcomers or Starters** is common in the UK for new employees but that may not hold outside. '**Inductees**' is a term used by HR departments but it is usually written rather than spoken.

Comment: +1 Hi Nigel, good to see that you're linking to sources. I've added a simple citation to the definition so it's easy to see where the definition came from.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the term *veteran*.

> **veteran** *noun*
>   1 A person who has had long experience in a particular field.
>   ‘He has become the spine of a team which blends experienced veterans and youth.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/veteran)

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U. Your post contained an answer as well as a comment on another post. I've taken the liberty of removing the comment as it obscures your answer. I've also added a dictionary definition, with a link and citation, together with a relevant example from the dictionary entry. This helps others more objectively see why your suggestion is a good answer to the question. Please feel free to [edit] further or to roll back the changes.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm new to this so any direction is much appreciated!